# How can I calculate $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{a}{b + X}\right)$?

Tags: probability

If $X \sim \mathrm{bin}(n, p)$ and $a, b$ are constants, how can I calculate $\mathbb{E}\left(\dfrac{a}{b + X}\right)$? Sorry that I am quite rusty, and can't figure that out. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that you do not have enough information to compute this. At most you can obtain an inequality with Jensen, with additional assumptions on $a, b$

Comment: Can this be used $$\mathbb{E}(\frac{a}{b+X})=\mathbb{E}(\frac ab(1-\frac Xb +(\frac Xb)^2-\cdots)$$

Comment: @BGM does it need the probability distribution of `X` to calculate the expectation?  In my case $x$ has a binomial distribution $(n,p)$.

Comment: Anyway, if $b$ is a positive integer then $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{a}{b+X}\right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ a\int_{0}^{1} t^{b+X-1} \, dt \right]
= a\int_{0}^{1} t^{b-1}(1-p+pt)^n \, dt $$ allows you to compute the expectation in a closed form, but otherwise we seem out of luck.